# Setting and checking localstorage for a certain value, then performing a function based on the data

Tags: javascript, html, function, local-storage

I'm trying to set local storage from one page("index.html/settest.html"), and check for it on "index.html". If the check comes back with a certain result, it'll execute a function.

I have written some code for this, but it doesn't work. I don't really know why, so I'm hoping to get some assistance here.

Here's what I have on my "settest.html" page. It's really simple -

```
        <script>
            window.onload=setlocalstorage() {
                localStorage.setItem("one", true);
            }
        </script>
```

So the way I understand it, when the page loads, it should set the value of "one" to true in localStorage.

Here's what I have on my "index.html" page -

```
<script>
    window.onload=setInterval(function() {
        var one = localStorage.getItem('one') || '';
        if (one != 'yes') {
            function hideone() {
                var elem = document.getElementById("one");
                elem.className = "hide";
            }
        }
    }, 1000);
</script>
```

From what I understand, this should check localStorage every second for "one", and execute the function "hideone" if it comes back yes(or true).

However, when I go to "settest.html", and then visit "index.html", nothing happens. There are no errors in the console, or anything abnormal showing. I just don't get why it won't work.

Thanks in advance, if anyone needs more information or context feel free to ask!

-Mitchyl

Comment: You seem to be misdefining the function.

Comment: The first window.onload is just a syntax error ?

Comment: Crap. Thanks guys, I knew it was something simple like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not defining the `window.onload` functions correctly. Either:

```
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        localStorage.setItem("one", true);
    }
</script>
```

Or:

```
<script>
    window.onload = loadFunction;
    function loadFunction() {
        localStorage.setItem("one",true);
    }
</script>
```

And on your other page:

```
window.onload = function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        var one = localStorage.getItem('one') || '';
        if (one != 'yes') {
            function hideone() {
                var elem = document.getElementById("one");
                elem.className = "hide";
            }
        }
    }, 1000);
};
```

Additionally, you're setting `localStorage.one` to `true` on the first page, and checking if it's `yes` on the other page. Not sure if this is meant to be or is a mistake.

Comment: I don't know if I'm correct in this, but I was told that "yes" and "true" were equal. I've changed it though.

Comment: The strings `yes` and `true` are not equal. Perform an equality check: in your browser's console, type `'true'==='yes'`. Should return false.

Comment: However, when evaluated with an `if` statement, 'yes' (a non-empty string) is superficially equal to `true`. You should still use `true` in both cases though.

Comment: Huh. Thanks for the info! I'm actually learning a ton. Thanks for all the awesome answers :)

Comment: Yep. Was just implementing everything and making sure I had no extra questions. Once again, thanks so much.

Comment: No problem, that's why we're here :)

Answer (score 0):

None of your functions are correctly defined. It looks like you want to do this:

settest.html:

```
<script>
    window.onload=function()
    {
        localStorage.setItem("one", true);
    }
</script>
```

index.html:

```
<script>
    window.onload = function ()
    {
        setInterval(function()
        {
            var one = localStorage.getItem('one') || '';
            if (one !== true)
            {
                var elem = document.getElementById("one");
                elem.className = "hide";
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
</script>
```

Assuming you want it to check every second to see if it needs to set the class on a specific element to 'hide'.

Comment: God, I feel like a fool. Thanks for your help, guys!